# Nested for loop executing weirdly

Tags: bash

I'm currently trying to run a check to download an index file for each entry in a csv, match a last downloaded id to the index and see if it's present. But it is currently only executing the last downloaded id once.

```
            checkIndex() {
        for log in $(cat "$2/$3/logs.index")
        do
                temp=$(echo "$1" | tr -d '\r')
                echo "$temp"
                if [ $temp == $log ]; then
                        return 1
                fi
        done
    
     sed 1d $csvfile | while IFS=, read -r site id key url conf
            do
                    conf=$(echo "$conf" | tr -d '\r')
                    curr=$(cat "$CONF_DIR$conf/LastKnownDownloadedFileId_curr.txt")
                    site=$(echo "$site" | tr -d '\r')
                    id=$(echo "$id" | tr -d '\r')
                    key=$(echo "$key" | tr -d '\r')
                    url=$(echo "$url" | tr -d '\r')
                    index="logs.index"
                    echo "$site $id $key $url $conf"
                    if [ ! -d "$TEMPDIR/$site" ]; then
                            mkdir -p "$TEMPDIR/$site"
                    fi
                    wget -q --user=$id --password=$key $url$index -O $TEMPDIR/$site/logs.index
    
                    checkIndex $curr $TEMPDIR $site
```

However the output is something like this

```
 testsite testid testkey https://testurl/ testconf
 9248_2147.log vs 9248_2049.log 
 9248_2050.log
 9248_2051.log
 9248_2052.log 
 9248_2053.log
 9248_2054.log 
 9248_2055.log
```

Comment: `| tr -d '\r'` it's simpler to do it once `sed 1d "$csvfile" | tr -d '\r' | while...` instead of every time one after another. Check your script with shellcheck

Comment: Could you also include the input file so we can run the script ourselves?

Comment: @KamilCuk ahh thank you! I tried it earlier with the tr -d '\r' after the while and it didnt work so i just stuck with calling it indivudually.

Comment: @choroba unfortunately the input file contains credential information hence i'm unable to share. but i've managed to fix it and posted the resolution in the answer although i still have no idea what is the reasoning behind whats actually happening

Answer (score 0):

Sorry all! turns out it was an issue of declaring IFS="," at the top of my script. I was trying to remove unneeded code and after removing IFS="," it worked properly.